# Gradient tool bar slider disappears when I click and release the mouse Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, creative-cloud

I am just wanting the gradient bar slider to stay when I am using the gradient tool. Whenever I click and drag it disappears? I am not sure what it is called but I found an image in the photoshop application it looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is simply how Photoshop works.

The direction indicator preview will *not* stay visible once you release the click. 
There is **nothing** you can to about that.

---

You *may* be thinking of **Illustrator** which *does* have a gradient annotator which remains visible when the Gradient Tool is active.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the normal behaviour..it should stay on, I use the beta version and sometimes it stays on and somtimes it dissapears..but I don't figure why is this.. If I restart the app it works again..

Comment: Aren't Adobe beta testers required to sign a non-disclosure agreement, which would prevent you from stating you are beta tester let alone stating you are using a beta version.